# Strange behaviour when copy/pasting bash commands with heredocs into terminal

Tags: bash, heredoc

To simplify some processes I document a large series of terminal commands so I can copy and paste them when needed.

I'm encountering some strange behaviour however, as demonstrated here:

```
ssh $USER@$SERVER 'rm ~/backup.tar'

tar -xvzf backup.tar
cd backup
```

When I copy all of that and paste it into a terminal, the SSH command is executed, resulting in a pause as it runs. Once it finishes, the `tar` and `cd` commands are not executed - as if they were never copied.

I surmise this is because they're somehow being "typed" (I know that's not the right word) while the SSH command is still executing, and are hence consumed by that command - doing nothing there.

Sure, that makes sense, but it gets weird here:

```
ssh $USER@$SERVER 'rm ~/backup.tar' <<EOF
EOF

tar -xvzf backup.tar
cd backup
```

This seems like the same thing but with some random, purposeless heredoc. However when I've got it there, the `tar` and `cd` commands are successfully pasted and executed after the SSH command completes.

**And so my question:**

What difference did the heredoc make that caused `tar` and `cd` to be pasted as I would've originally expected?

Is there a better way than randomly slugging on a heredoc to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a command normally, the standard input of the process is connected to the terminal. Any characters that the terminal program receives are passed on to the process. But when you run a command with a redirection, like the heredoc you used, the standard input of the process is connected to a memory buffer containing the contents of the heredoc. In this case, characters the terminal program receives don't get passed on to the process; instead, they get saved, and after the process finishes, then the terminal program figures out what to do with them.

As far as how to fix it: the best way is probably to use a shell script, instead of copying and pasting. But if you can't do that for some reason, the redirection seems like a reasonable solution. Instead of providing a heredoc you could just run

```
ssh $USER@$SERVER 'rm ~/backup.tar' </dev/null
```

Comment: Why do we think we want to provide that input at all? With a command on the line ssh shouldn't be looking at input at all. The `ssh` command won't return until the command finishes that's not an input issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` reads standard input. If you supply a HERE doc, it takes its input from it, so doesn't read the real stdin with the commands.

Answer (score 0):

In first example `tar` and `cd` command went to stdin of ssh. In the second the stdin of ssh was terminated and therefore bash executed `tar` and `cd`